# How can switch Windows pop-up in Internet Explorer in Selenium Webdriver using JAVA?

Tags: selenium

I am unable to switch windows pop-up in internet explorer. I checked the security setting there intranet setting is not enable mode and we don't have admin  access to change. Can any one help me on this

```
    String handle= driver.getWindowHandle(); 
    System.out.println(handle); 
    driver.findElement(By.name("New Message Window")).click(); 
    Set handles = driver.getWindowHandles(); 
    System.out.println(handles); 
    for (String handle1 : driver.getWindowHandles()) { 
       System.out.println(handle1); 
       driver.switchTo().window(handle1); 
       System.out.println(driver.getTitle()); //Trying to print Title here

    }
```

Comment: are you getting any errors? what have you tried?

Comment: I am trying to switch from parent to child window .there is one link ,once i am clicking the link pop-up is getting displayed,but after that i am unable to switch to the window

Comment: String handle= driver.getWindowHandle();
 
         System.out.println(handle);
 
        
driver.findElement(By.name("New Message Window")).click();
 
                       
Set handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
 System.out.println(handles);
 
    
for (String handle1 : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
 
          System.out.println(handle1);
 
          driver.switchTo().window(handle1);
 
          }

Comment: I am not getting any error as well,but when i am trying to print thec child  window title message it is printing  the parent window name only.

Comment: Update the code in you post to where you tried print title

Comment: Updated..still same issue